# Wordpress nonce always returning false

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, nonce

I have a problem in my wordpress API where the nonce used for verification always returns false. I have tried logging out in and out, API works fine with authentication turned off. I'll include the code below.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'api_init');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script');

function api_init() {
    register_rest_route("route/v1/", "/directory/(?P<req>\d+)", array(
            "methods" => ["GET", "POST"],
            "callback" => "api_delegate",
            "permission_callback" => current_user_can("relevant_cap")
    ));

}

function enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_name', '/path/to/ajax/script.js', ['jquery'], '1.0.4', false);

    wp_localize_script('script_name', 'ajax_var', array(
        "url" => esc_url_raw("https://relevant_url.com/"),
        "nonce" => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
    ));
}
```

And for the clientside Javascript

```
    $(".api").on('click', order66());

    function order66() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/wp-json/relevant/v1/',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {
                "_wpnonce": ajax_var.nonce
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            },
            // contentType: 'application/json',
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

I have also attempted using the "X-WP-Nonce" header but that did not give any different result. any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Visit https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/

Comment: Had a look found nothing too suprising, localization objects can be accessed fine on the client side. I think I'm either passing or generating them incorrectly somehow but I'm not sure how else to do it

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I needed to wrap the "permission callback" with an anonymous function, after that it worked like a charm!